# Some web sites render differently when returning from link

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I'm using an iPhone 6s with iOS 9.3.4 and Safari.  I am encountering a problem when I view certain websites: if I tap a link to be taken to another page and then swipe right to return to the page I was first viewing, the site doesn't display the same way it originally did.  The font and everything else is much larger (as if I hit ⌘+ on desktop Safari to enlarge everything).  Please visit the link just below to imgur.com to see a before and after view of the problem:

[Before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCk5E.jpg)

(Meta: I originally embedded both images directly into this post, but StackExchange wouldn't let me embed more than 2 links so I felt it better to save my second link and use it below to link to a particular site where this problem can be replicated for the benefit of those who want to try this with their mobile device.)

I can't say for sure this started happening when I recently upgraded from 9.3.3 to 9.3.4, but I started noticing it right around that time, and I can't remember it ever having happened before that.

Here's a few things about it:

- Refreshing the page fixes the problem and reverts it to its previous formatting, but that's becoming annoying, and more importantly, it unnecessarily pushes me closer to my cellular data usage cap.
- It doesn't happen on all sites.  But when I do encounter a site it happens on, I am able to replicate the problem every time I try.
- Turning off my content blocker does not help.

Strangely, triggering the enlarging behavior depends on what link/site I tap to visit.  Using [the site](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2016/08/python-packaging.html) pictured in the images linked above for example: there is a hyperlink not far from the top of the page in the paragraph under the heading "The Dark Age" denoted by the text "**dumb idea**."  Tapping that link *does not* trigger the behavior when I return from it.  However, in the paragraph just below it there's another link denoted by the text "**other projects entirely outside of programming**."  Tapping this link and returning from it *does* trigger the enlarging.

Is anyone else able to replicate this on their iPhone in Safari?  Does anyone know if there's anything I can do on my end to stop this from happening?

Comment: I've had this happen too. I have not found a fix

Comment: I just downloaded Chrome and I can't repeat the problem.  Which seems odd to me given that they both use the same rendering engine.